# Не работает SQL-запрос в phpmyadmin

Tags: php, phpmyadmin, mysqli

```
SELECT * FROM 'categories' INNER JOIN movie
```

Ответ MySQL:

> ## 1064 - У вас ошибка в запросе. Изучите документацию по используемой версии MariaDB на предмет корректного синтаксиса около ''categories' INNER JOIN movie LIMIT 0, 25' на строке 1

Comment: нужно указывать, по каким полям джойним. SELECT * FROM 'categories' INNER JOIN movie ON movie.id_category = categories.id

Comment: Вы используете неправильные кавычки для квотирования имени таблицы. С прямой кавычкой `'` - это не имя таблицы, а строковый литерал. Используйте обратную кавычку `\``.

Comment: Спасибо, помогли